# No WiFi on IntelNUC Following Release Upgrade

Tags: networking, wireless, upgrade

The Ubuntu installation on my NUC had been reminding me that a release upgrade was available for a while. I've finally relented, only to find I no longer have a network connection, wireless or ethernet. I've found the wireless info script, and run that, but nothing obvious is leaping out at me, although I'll admit to being completely out of my depth here... Once I've figured out how to upload the script output, I will.

Presumably it's a driver issue of some sort, but I'm struggling to figure it out. Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Dropbox link to archive with wireless-inro output:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/m48wy5x8jbsx3u4/wireless-info.tar.gz?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you have Network Manager running, you have also, erroneously, declared the wireless interface in Netplan. I suggest that you revert your file */etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml* to read as follows:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Follow with:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

Reboot.

Comment: Thank you, that's got it.