# Wlan0 will not connect to WiFi?

Tags: wireless, network-manager, netplan

I'm trying to run a USB Wi-Fi dongle off Ubuntu Server. I edited `/etc/netplan/*.yaml` and I'm running multiple network interfaces, which all work as intended. See the lines below for the Wi-Fi setting. Renderer is `NetworkManager`.

```
  wifis:
wlan0:
  access-points:
    "SSID":
      password: "********"
  dhcp4: true
  optional: true
```

I'm able to see the `wlan0` interface and scan:

```
wlan0     Scan completed :
      Cell 01 - Address: 1C:43:63:26:2C:DC
                Channel:9
                Frequency:2.452 GHz (Channel 9)
                Quality=42/70  Signal level=-68 dBm
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"SSID"
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                          9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Mode:Master
                Extra:tsf=0000000e5148e399
                Extra: Last beacon: 72ms ago
```

Logs from `NetworkManager`:

```
Nov 27 17:21:43 sp4k001 NetworkManager[2312]: <info>  [1669569703.6108] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: starting -> ready
Nov 27 17:21:43 sp4k001 NetworkManager[2312]: <info>  [1669569703.6111] Wi-Fi P2P device controlled by interface wlan0 created
Nov 27 17:21:43 sp4k001 NetworkManager[2312]: <info>  [1669569703.6117] manager: (p2p-dev-wlan0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi P2P device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/5)
Nov 27 17:21:43 sp4k001 NetworkManager[2312]: <info>  [1669569703.6125] device (p2p-dev-wlan0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Nov 27 17:21:43 sp4k001 NetworkManager[2312]: <warn>  [1669569703.6141] sup-iface: failed to cancel p2p connect: P2P cancel failed
Nov 27 17:21:43 sp4k001 NetworkManager[2312]: <info>  [1669569703.6142] device (p2p-dev-wlan0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Nov 27 17:21:43 sp4k001 NetworkManager[2312]: <info>  [1669569703.6147] device (wlan0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
```

Any ideas? I've tried with and without `wpa_supplicant`, but Netplan.io says you don't need `wpa_supplicant` when running `NetworkManager` backend.

I've also found the following logs in `netplan-wpa-wlan0.service`:

```
Nov 27 16:18:53 sp4k001 wpa_supplicant[3908]: wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 1c:43:63:26:2c:dc (SSID='Hairy-Lemon' freq=2452 MHz)
Nov 27 16:18:53 sp4k001 wpa_supplicant[3908]: wlan0: Trying to associate with 1c:43:63:26:2c:dc (SSID='Hairy-Lemon' freq=2452 MHz)
Nov 27 16:18:53 sp4k001 wpa_supplicant[3908]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="Hairy-Lemon" auth_failures=7 duration=90 reason=CONN_FAILED
Nov 27 16:20:24 sp4k001 wpa_supplicant[3908]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=0 ssid="Hairy-Lemon"
Nov 27 16:20:24 sp4k001 wpa_supplicant[3908]: wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with 1c:43:63:26:2c:dc (SSID='Hairy-Lemon' freq=2452 MHz)
Nov 27 16:20:24 sp4k001 wpa_supplicant[3908]: wlan0: Trying to associate with 1c:43:63:26:2c:dc (SSID='Hairy-Lemon' freq=2452 MHz)
Nov 27 16:20:25 sp4k001 wpa_supplicant[3908]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="Hairy-Lemon" auth_failures=8 duration=90 reason=CONN_FAILED
```

When I run `nmcli dev wifi connect SSID password ******`, it all works. Am I not able to use `netplan` and `NetworkManager` without reliance on `wpa_supplicant`? Any help appreciated, this seems to be a common problem for quite a few people on Ubuntu Server.

To clarify, this is not resolved via the following steps: [No WiFi on IntelNUC Following Release Upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1442481/no-wifi-on-intelnuc-following-release-upgrade)

Out of the box, I'm not able to set up a netplan and attach a Wi-Fi connection to an AP with PSK. See error messages above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to bring this back, it was a driver issue when wpasupplicant was passing information to the an rtl82xxx driver that Ubuntu is not familiar with. I was using a TP-Link Mini N300 USB adapter, which was the cause of the strange behaviour. Edimax EW-7811 seem to work fine with their rtl8192cu chip in Ubuntu with Netplan.

Running Netplan as normal with NetworkManager renderer, with wpasupplicant installed worked well. Just make sure your devices and services aren't conflicting.

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer your question, but NetworkManager does rely on wpasupplicant for the WiFi authentication. The only difference is that if you install NetworkManager, this is pulled in *automatically*.  If you are using networkd, then you need to manually install it.

The logs simply look like a bad wifi password.  You can check under `/run/NetworkManager` to make sure the file emitted by netplan has the correct password, and that you're not being caught out by some yaml escaping issue.

Comment: I'm back on this as I'm having the same issue with another Wifi adapter. I can see the correct settings in /run/NetworkManager/. If I unplug the WiFi adapter and plug it back in, it will connect to the network successfully. I can repeat this over and over, I've also seen a bug was reported on launchpad and people are still asking about it - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netplan.io/+bug/1874377